# Ways to prove if the given matrix is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

show that the set of 2x2 matix of the form

$$\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is a vector space with the standard operations

can i incorporate the idea that this certain matrix can be connected (a subspace) to the $M_{2\times 2}$ with real entries matrix, which has been proven in our class to be a vector space? or not since it has not been stated in the problem and prove this using the 10 axioms?

Comment: A subspace has to be a vector space also. I do not quite understand how incorporating your matrices into a larger vector space makes that task easier. That being said: the task is quite simple.

Comment: First, `pmatrix` produces the bracket symbol; as for your question, you may look up the definition of *subspace* as well as its criterion. This might be what you want.

Comment: You seem to know that $M_{2\times 2}$ is a vector space with the usual operations. So yes, you can show that this subset of $M_{2\times 2}$ with the usual operations is a vector space by checking that it is a subspace (using the Subspace Test) and hence a vector space. So you don't need to prove the 10 axioms hold, that work has been done in general when you prove (i) that every subspace is a vector space and (ii) the Subspace Test

Comment: thank you @ancientmathematician, this was actually the answer that i was looking for, even though the construction of the question was quite unclear on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear but I assume you want to prove that the set of matrices
\begin{align}
\mathcal{M}=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}\mid a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}\right\}
\end{align}
form a real vector space. I think checking all the condition is the easiest method since most of them can be proven in a single line. I'll check three for you and you can work out the remaining ones!

$\textbf{closed under addition and scalar multiplication:}$
Suppose $\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & 0\\\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}
a' & b' \\
c' & 0\\\end{pmatrix}$ are matrices in $\mathcal{M}$ and $r$ is a real number then
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & 0\\\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}
a' & b' \\
c' & 0\\\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
a+a' & b+b' \\
c+c' & 0\\\end{pmatrix}\&\ r\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & 0\\\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
ra & rb \\
rc & 0\\\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
which are obviously again in $\mathcal{M}$.

$\textbf{commutativity:}$
This follows at once from the commuatativity of the real numbers.

$\textbf{identity of vector addition:}$
We have $\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0\\\end{pmatrix}\in\mathcal{M}$ and this is an identity since $0$ is the identity element of the addtion in the real numbers.

And so on and so forth.